# iOS app crashing only on iPhone 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have a very strange issue. Please help out. My app is crashing only on the iPhone 5s. There are no issues with other models; on iPhone 5, 5c, iPod it is working fine.

The problem is when I click on the app icon, the splash screen is appearing and crashing. It is not showing the root view. I have added splash images in the proper size. My `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function is below. Please tell me whether I need to modify anything in build settings or build phases or info.plist. I am using Crashlytics for crash logs and there no crash logs coming but I am getting crash logs when it crashed in other devices inside the application.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     ViewController *rootController=[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController " bundle:nil];
    _navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

    self.window.rootviewcontroller = _navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: just so you know, the 5S is a bit different to other models due to it having a 64bit processor, while the rest are 32bit. One thing to check for if you are using `floats` anywhere with `UITableView` delegate functions or something similar, make sure you are returning a `CGFloat` and not just a `float`, otherwise i cant really tell why it would be crashing like that

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error?

Comment: can you see any error message in log.If so do post that

Comment: There isn't much we can do without the stacktrace...

Comment: Probably you use some third-party tool, which initializes when app starts (e.g. analytics) which has problems with 64bit processor

Comment: without analytics also it is crashing...No floats and no UITableViews in before loading first viewcontoller....NO ERROR... NO CRASH Log...i stuck up with it from long time.....before loding the first view controller it is crashing...

Comment: Place breakpoint in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and walk through the code.

Comment: Add exceptions breakpoint and then you'll see the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to find an issue without any crash logs or errors. I would like to check if the application really crashed or was it any exit(-1) statement which caused the application to exit. Some frameworks like CoreData inserts exit statements in the code. Try searching for exit(-1) in your code. You can also

1. Put NSLog in various methods of AppDelegate and see where it crashes.
2. You can use a try-catch block in main method.

`@try{..} @catch(NSException *ex){NSLog(@"%@",ex.debugDescription);}`

in your main method in main.m. This should help you in finding if there is any exception at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old but today I was running into an issue with crashes on all devices and simulators older than iPhone 6 and it turned out to be some bug with Taplytics. I'm sure it's temporary but commenting out

`Taplytics.startTaplyticsAPIKey("XXXXX")`

in App Delegate fixed my issue